# CursorAdapter not displaying elements in ListView

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to get a column of SQLITE database to a listview using a SimpleCursorColumn. I am getting the accurate number of rows in the list view, but the text is not appearing in the list. I printed out the content of the cursor and it contains the correct elements.

Why is the text not showing up in the list? Surely it must be easy that I am being stupid about.

```
        public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int LOADER_ID = 42;
    private CursorAdapter _adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_frag, container, false);

        ListView lv = view.findViewById(R.id.student_view);
        _adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(),
                R.layout.container_list_item_view, null,
                new String[] { Contract.Student_Table.STUDENTS_COLUMN_NAME},
                new int[] { R.id.list_item });
        lv.setAdapter(_adapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        if (id != LOADER_ID) {
            return null;
        }
        return new CursorLoader(getContext(),
                Contract.Student_Table.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { Contract.Student_Table.STUDENTS_COLUMN_ID, Contract.Student_Table.STUDENTS_COLUMN_NAME}, null, null,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        _adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        _adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

**tab3_frag.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#c2f6ff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/simple_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Based on theme , sometimes textcolor could be same as the color of the background, try changing text color.

Comment: Sadly that wasn't it.

Comment: @Danger I've added the xml file, maybe a glaring mistake there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better use loader. Try below example:

```
public class LanguageListActivity extends ListActivity implements
        LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private static final int LOADER_ID = 42;
    private CursorAdapter _adapter;
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.container_list);
        _adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.container_list_item_view, null,
                new String[] { DatabaseConstants.COL_LANG_NAME },
                new int[] { R.id.list_item });
        setListAdapter(_adapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        if (id != LOADER_ID) {
            return null;
        }
        return new CursorLoader(LanguageListActivity.this,
                LanguageContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { DatabaseConstants.COL_LANG_ID, DatabaseConstants.COL_LANG_NAME }, null, null,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        _adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        _adapter.swapCursor(null);
  }
}
```

container_list.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

container_list_item_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: given that I this is from within a fragment, most of this will not work I'm afraid

Comment: There is nothing to worry about. implement LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> to your fragment. and start writing code. Most of the methods which are not available, you will be able to get by getContext(). If you donot want to do these all changes.. Create a new xml file for item like container_list_item_view.xml and put id student_view to the textview, remove it from the main layout where the listview is.. this should also work..

Comment: Because of the fragment, im not able to implement setListAdapter or give a proper callback when initializing the loader. Any work arounds? I've looked into a few but they all require API specific build, which is bad

Comment: Read my above comment. I have edited it. Also in Columns only take one value STUDENTS_COLUMN_NAME

Comment: I've updated my post above, I've been able to implement the adapter to a list view in another away, however, getting the callback function, the third parameter of the .initLoader() seems to be impossible without changing a large portion of my code. Or do you know of another way?

Comment: Ok i got it work, instead of using loadermanager.initLoader, i used getActivity().getLoaderManager().initLoader